# how to eliminate an element in a structure array in c

Tags: c

How do i create a function to  eliminate an element in an array of structure, c programming. my homework was to create a data system for a clinic that stores the information a patients and that deletes a registered patient in the clinic. here is some of my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
 #include<string.h>


struct Client
{
char namec[30];
char sex[100];
char suggested_medication[200];
int age;
};


void showcliente(struct Client *itens,int s)
{


   int l,op;
 int num=s+1;
```

> //dont worry about the num, everytime a cliente registers i return the
>   postion number and add it by one.

```
 printf("enter position: ");
 scanf("%i",&l);
   for (l=0;l< num;l++) {

      printf("name: %s \n", itens[l].namec);
  printf("age : %i \n", itens[l].age);
  printf("Sex : %s \n", itens[l].sex);
  printf("Tipo de enfermidade %s \n", itens[l].suggested_medication);
  printf("\n\n");
  printf("**********************************");

   } 

 getch();
  system("cls");

}

 main()           
{
system("COLOR F9");

int n=-1,op;

struct Cliente* itens = malloc(40*sizeof(struct Cliente));

struct Cliente *funC(int i)
{
    n=n+1;
  printf(" patients name: "); 
  scanf(" %[^\t\n]s",&itens[n].namec);
     printf(" age: ");
  scanf("%i",&itens[n].age);
  printf(" Sex: ");
  scanf("%s",&itens[n].sex); 
  printf("suggested medication: ");
  scanf(" %[^\t\n]s",&itens[n].suggested_medication);
        system("pause");
        system("cls");
  return itens;


}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the question it is clear that you need to create all the client's node dynamically. And delete them when you need. Or even better you can try to create a linked list out of these nodes and manage them as you need.

So in answer to the question, the best way to go about it will be to allocate memory as you need and then use them. When a client's information is not needed you can try to delete them.

What you are doing is allocating 40 or so client at once. The best way would be to do one by one as needed. You can dynamically allocate memory using `malloc` and free them using `free()`. Also to read a line of input you may want to use `fgets()`.

Comment: i see..... the problem with freeing, is that if i free the data i wont be able to consult them when i need too. or can i use free() as a form of eliminating??

Comment: @MarcioQuiteque.: You will free when you dont need them any more. Otherwise you can also make another linked list called `deletedRecords` where you will keep all your deleted records. And that way you can access them when you want it. You get what I mean?

Comment: @MarcioQuiteque.: You get any help from th answeR?

Comment: ya, you gave me an idea